Is it "bad" to install a system package in a docker entryPoint script?
I've got an AWS ECS service that includes several containers that are nearly identical.  I've initially built this with a dockerfile for each image, and it works fine but the builds are really slow, with a lot of duplicated effort.  Building a single base image for all the containers seems like the Docker way to do this, but results in some overhead and seems like overkill so I am avoiding it.
I can solve this more easily by starting each container with a different entryPoint file BUT it means that at least one of the entryPoints would install a system package or two, and that feels a little "dirty."  I'm talking about things like apt-get install ....  But I can't think of any real problems with this, besides a bit slower startup.
Is this a terrible idea?  Are there other issues I should be considering before installing packages in my entryPoint instead of in the docker image build?

Building a single base image for all the containers seems like the Docker way to do this, but results in some overhead and seems like overkill so I am avoiding it. what overhead are you concerned about?

Is this a terrible idea? Are there other issues I should be considering before installing packages in my entryPoint instead of in the docker image build? Biggest problem I would see here is that installing the packages might fail for some reason.

@t.niese Thanks for the comments.  I'm building/testing locally and deploying to AWS ecs repo's and it's just easier to simply not to build an intermediate image at all.  Good point regarding the possibility of install failure, i.e, a new dependency on all the related install servers, etc.

I still don’t see why having multiple docker images is a problem. You do not even need a base image, the same thing you do with the entry points could be done with building arguments to decide what packets to install during build.

You should include all of the packages you need in your image build.
Trying to install things in your image's entrypoint script...

...is slow; apt-get update && apt-get install takes at least a couple of seconds even on good hardware, and this limits your startup time
...makes you vulnerable to hiccups outside your control in the remote repository or in the network
...makes you vulnerable to the remote repository rate-limiting you for repeatedly requesting lots of package installs
...can cause your image to fail if the remote repository happens to include an incompatible change, outside your control
...and all of these things can happen in production

If everything is included in your image, and then there's an outage in the remote repositories, you won't be able to rebuild your image until they come back, but you'll still be able to launch new containers, scale up and scale down, and so on.  If there is a package change in the remote repository, you won't see it until it passes through your CI system, and get a chance to run system tests on it.
Depending on how similar your images really are, you might be able to share a slightly larger image with multiple containers.  One common example is a Web server and background worker sharing much of the same code base; the worker doesn't need the Web server per se, but if it can share the same image and override the command then you can save a build.  Similarly, a couple extra OS packages in a shared Docker layer isn't usually going to be a big space problem.

Thanks.  That's what I concluded... that adding a package or two to a shared-use container is just fine (but installing in entryPoint can be actually problematic.)  Who ferrets through a standard base build to worry about a few things you don't need anyway?  It seems like building images with some actually-unnecessary packages is actually the norm.
